# Set Margin between cards and bottom but keep scrollbar as it is

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

got stucked into CSS...

on

```
[http://codepen.io/n00n/pen/RoqWJy][1]
```

you will see an example what I would like to to. 
But would like to have a margin cuttin the card at bottom like it is on top where the scroll bar still gets till the red bar.... But cannot get it fixed. 
Anybody who has any hint?

cu s00n
de n00n

Comment: Scrolling elements do not paint content outside of it's element. This is controlled by the overflow property. The way to do it is probably to make a fixed "background" and scroll on top of it.

Comment: no, it is a container with cards in it. would like to scroll the card, bot with margin where they get cut...

Answer (score 0):

After a while I come to the conclusion that it is impossible. Will find another way to solve it